# Detection range of unintentional emissions by battery powered video recording devices?

Tags: rf, security, em

I have read about unintentional radiators, but wonder about what their unwanted emissions detection range can be in low background noise, referring to battery powered motion-sensor activated video recorders with local storage.
Would there be, apart from EMF emission also the possibility of ultrasound noise coming from microprocessors or other circuit components?
Which unwanted signals would be more likely to stand out?

Thank you

Comment: What does ultrasound have to do with electromagnetic emissions?

Comment: As far as I know there is no regulatory concept of "unintentional radiator" that applies to acoustic emissions. However, sometimes designers do take steps to minimize acoustic emissions from inductors and capacitors and motor windings. One way to help with this is to keep the switching frequency above 20kHz so that humans will not hear the acoustic emissions.

Comment: Inductors transformers and motors frequently emit audible noises when switched in the audible range. Ceramic capacitors also function as transducers. They are able to produce noise under rapidly changing voltage, and also produce voltage spikes or noise when subjected to mechanical force (impact, etc).

Comment: So you're asking about sound and EMI? Because you lead with "unintentional radiator" which is a term in the FCC codes which is EMI only, but then start talking about sound.

Comment: @DKNguyen: I'd like to know about any kind of emission that a battery powered device as described could produce and hence be detected.

Comment: What is the application of this question?  Is it for detecting intentionally hidden recording devices or transmitters?

Comment: The edit seems to totally change the meaning of the question. Or at least how I understood it. I believe that the acoustic emissions of typical low powered devices are generally so low that the devices can be considered totally silent. The idea that acoustic methods could be used to detect hidden surveillance equipment does not seem very promising to me. I have only encountered audible noise from high power events such as high current inrush, and higher voltage (like 50V) PWM for motors. Handheld battery devices do not make noise (except through the speakers).

Comment: I am not sure how trail cameras work. How do they know when an animal is in the field of view at night? Do they do passive IR detection, or some type of active signal like ultrasound. Or do they capture images at a low rate in the dark using IR illuminators until motion is detected?

Comment: “Hidden” as in hidden from sight or hidden to hide the emissions?